# salt error : "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found"

Tags: devops, salt-stack

Getting below error while running salt command like:
salt "" state.sls export-job

Can some one help on this issue ?

```
  Function: pkg.installed
      Result: False
     Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1745, in call
                  **cdata['kwargs'])
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1702, in wrapper
                  return f(*args, **kwargs)
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/pkg.py", line 1442, in installed
                  **kwargs)
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/aptpkg.py", line 637, in install
                  deb_info = __salt__['lowpkg.bin_pkg_info'](pkg_source)
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/dpkg.py", line 67, in bin_pkg_info
                  if not os.path.exists(path):
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
                  os.stat(path)
              TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found
     Started: 08:29:27.066443
    Duration: 39.616 ms
     Changes:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this page --> https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/12400. they are talking about the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Salt does not throw appropriate error message that's why all the mess. In my case data.sls had entry of a package name which was removed from the location before running this script by another salt script.

Whenever you get this error then there should be missing file/directory from the given path.

It would be great if salt throws error with exact message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was printing values from more than one table.  In the first table, it had this schema:

```
| ORDINAL_POSITION | COLUMN_NAME   | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | IS_NULLABLE |
|                1 | DateTimeStamp | datetime  | NULL                     | NO          |
|                2 | DataVal       | nvarchar  | -1                       | NO          |
```

These printed without a problem.  Then in the second table, it had this schema:

```
| ORDINAL_POSITION | COLUMN_NAME   | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | IS_NULLABLE |
|                1 | DateTimeStamp | datetime  | NULL                     | NO          |
|                2 | DataVal       | bit       | NULL                     | NO          |
```

As soon as the print line was reached for the second table, it threw this `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found error`:

```
        for myValue in tableValues:
            print str(myValue.dateTimeStamp)+', '+myValue.dataVal
```

So to avoid this I simply cast all values to string:

```
        for myValue in tableValues:
            print str(myValue.dateTimeStamp)+', '+str(myValue.dataVal)
```